# Cmd-K shortcut for searching in Safari 4

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, safari, google-search

I really love (and am used to) the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut of Firefox for the google search field. How can I add a <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut in Safari for the Google Search field ?

I found [this article](http://5thirtyone.com/archives/506) that explains how to do it, but while it worked with safari 3, it does not work with safari 4. I am on Snow Leopard (in french), if it does matter... (yes, I noticed that the three dots are actually one special character and not three simple dots...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation on the site of the link you gave is still correct - almost.
You need to change "Google Search…" to 
a) the **localized expression** (in the german Safari for ex. it's called "Google-Suche …")
b) **and add a space** in between the expression and the triple dots.

You'll find the correct expression unter Edit > Search... (or whatever that would be in french. Maybe Modifier > Recherche...)

Hope I could help and ... une belle journée. :-)

Comment: That's what I was looking for ! Merci ;) !

Answer (score 5):

Not the fastest way, but in case you cannot solve it: I always hit Cmd-L, Tab. That is: Cmd-L to get to the location bar, and then Tab to go to the search box. If you happen to be in a Top Sites view, then hitting Tab twice again gets you to Search History.

Comment: And it works on any Mac, not just your own tweaked machine.

Answer (score 4):

There is Cmd + Option + F for activating search field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially of interest: **[OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/solutions/homenetwork/shortcuts/)** has a great "shortcuts" feature that lets you use your address bar as a search field for any site you define.  Once you start using their (free) DNS service, you can configure, for example, "img safari" to search Google Images for 'safari', or "amz sedaris" to search Amazon for 'sedaris'.  You specify the URL and query placeholder, and they do the rest.